# How do I replace a certain user input ingredient with another ingredient from another table

Tags: java, sql

I'm building a java app that allows users to enter recipes (recipe name, ingredients) then choose what type of recipe they want (vegan, vegetarian, gluten-free, or lactose-intolerant). Then it will store the recipe into a database. I want it so where if they enter grilled cheese and have recipe ingredients as 2slicesof bread and cheddar and chose the vegan option, the recipe would replace cheddar with cashew cheese or vegan cheese.

Comment: Have a replacement table. LEFT JOIN. COALESCE.

Comment: Can you elaborate?